# AWS Route 53 problem DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

On AWS we have 2 Elastic Beanstalk instances and one S3 bucket for a static website. Since app used Login With Amazon we added https protocol. Recently we moved a domain to Route 53, created SSL certificates and configured Load Balancers with https for each of instances.

The website/elastic instances work well when addressed to generic by AWS domains.
But we faced with a problem when using the created domain on route 53. Sometimes domain is not available and we don't know why (see attached video). [Failed to open route 53 domain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdBV5VPLAmE)

This issue reproduces on Safari when you refresh a web page many times and our servers become unavailable. We spent 1 week trying to fix this problem without any success. The real problem is that we don't even know what can be a reason. Any thoughts?
Thanks for any response!

Comment: I feel your pain, bro.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see from your domain informations you are pointing to an AWS IP-Address with an A-Record.

You should point your domain as "CNAME" to the AWS Url.

The IP of your Elastic Beanstalk Instances can change, the Elastic Beanstalk Url does not.

Greetings

Dominik

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I using A-Record only for `markid.io` that point to s3 bucket as a static website.

For 2 eb instances, I have subdomains such as `stagingapi.markid.io.` and use "CNAME" with generated by AWS domains values, Those subdomains can be unavailable at the same time with the `markid.io` domain but they always available by AWS generated domains.

weird.

Comment: Ok that looks good. I can not recreate your problem. Could it be your local internet connection and local dns provider? Can you change your local dns provider to 8.8.8.8 ? Another tip: For SSL you need to put cloudfront in front of your s3

Comment: This way it worked for me when using the DNS of ELB also.(For those who are getting 502 when ELB is configured)

Answer (score -2):

Resolved with this answer on AWS forum

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=295461

**Updated:**
Unfortunately, the link is broken and I can't remind myself how it was fixed. It was a few years ago...

Comment: after you updated the hosted zone ns (to the values that were in rt 53).... how long did it take before you were able to hit your https url?

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: Link is dead.. what is the fix, do you recall @Alex Voitenko ?

Comment: Link is dead, that is why you should post the answer and not a link to that

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken and I can't remind myself how it was fixed. It was a few years ago...